# Connect failed Oracle Express 10g on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, oracle10g, sqlplus

I just installed `oracle database express 10g` on `ubuntu`.

When I open `sqlplus` via terminal, I use this to login :

```
user-name : system
pasword : toor
```

`toor` is the password I given during oracle installation.

But I got this error :

> ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist

How can I sovle this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that there is probably an issue with the configuration of your listener. First you can check the status, stop, and start the listener service using the following:

status:

```
lsnrctl status
```

stop:

```
lsnrctl stop
```

start:

```
lsnrctl start
```

If that doesn't work it may be a configuration issue with the listener.ora file itself. The default listener.ora file should look like this:

```
LISTENER =
(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname)(PORT = port_number))
)
)
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
(SID_LIST =
(SID_DESC =
(SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
(ORACLE_HOME = oracle_product_home_directory)
(PROGRAM = extproc)
)
)
```

Hope this helps.

-V